# ""app name" failed to start several times. Restore it by clearing its history?"

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

The error:

> Failed to start several times. Restore it by clearing its history?

happens in some mobile manufacturers like OPPO, Samsung etc... And I found it only happens once the app is uninstalled then re-installed back through Play Store. It also happens after updating the app.

[image: Error Message]

It will only open up once I clear its data.

It should work as other apps, even if I uninstall and reinstall it back for testing purposes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest`, change:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

Comment: Looks as simple as this. It force to override by adding tools:replace="android:allowBackup" in manifest